# Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code : 500

Tags: java, websocket, jsf, primefaces

Есть проект с JSF, primefaces и atmosphere. После старта новой сессии примерно через 30 секунд вылетает ошибка:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/project/primepush/ticker?X-Atmosphere-tracking-id=0&X-Atmosphere-Framework=2.2.9-javascript&X-Atmosphere-Transport=websocket&X-Atmosphere-TrackMessageSize=true&X-atmo-protocol=true' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 500
        Websocket closed, reason: Connection was closed abnormally (that is, with no close frame being sent).
        Websocket failed. Downgrading to Comet and resending
```

Стэктрейс:

```
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleRead(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:90)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.TransportFilter.handleRead(TransportFilter.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.read(DefaultFilterChain.java:351)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.read(FilterChainContext.java:736)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.blockingRead(InputBuffer.java:1107)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.io.ServerInputBuffer.blockingRead(ServerInputBuffer.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.fill(InputBuffer.java:1131)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.io.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.InputBuffer.read(InputBuffer.java:267)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream.read(CoyoteInputStream.java:270)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read1(BufferedReader.java:210)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.read(BufferedReader.java:286)
    at java.io.Reader.read(Reader.java:140)
    at org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils.readEntirelyAsString(IOUtils.java:165)
    at org.atmosphere.util.IOUtils.readEntirely(IOUtils.java:116)
    at org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointHandlerProxy.onRequest(PushEndpointHandlerProxy.java:151)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.action(AsynchronousProcessor.java:206)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AsynchronousProcessor.suspended(AsynchronousProcessor.java:108)
    at org.atmosphere.container.GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport.service(GlassFishServ30WebSocketSupport.java:60)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework.doCometSupport(AtmosphereFramework.java:2241)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doPost(AtmosphereServlet.java:190)
    at org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereServlet.doGet(AtmosphereServlet.java:176)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:260)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read(TemporarySelectorReader.java:126)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.tmpselectors.TemporarySelectorReader.read(TemporarySelectorReader.java:75)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.AbstractReader.read(AbstractReader.java:72)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransportFilter.handleRead(TCPNIOTransportFilter.java:77)
    ... 63 more
```

web.xml

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.enableRestoreView11Compatibility</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.primefaces.push.PushServlet</servlet-class>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Push Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/primepush/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        180
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Фронт:

```
        <p:socket channel="/ticker">
            <p:ajax event="message" update="mainLayout"/>
        </p:socket>
```

Бэк:

```
@PushEndpoint("/ticker") 
public class Socket {

    @OnMessage(decoders = {JSONDecoder.class}, encoders = {JSONEncoder.class})
    public String onMessage(RemoteEndpoint remoteEndpoint, String str) {
        return str;
    }
}
```

Апдейт фронта:

```
public void updateTicker() {
    EventBus eventBus = EventBusFactory.getDefault().eventBus();
    eventBus.publish("/ticker", ticker);
}
```

Все происходит в ApplicationScoped бине. Исключение вылетает после старта новой сессии, примерно через 10 секунд. Судя по ошибке, атмосфера не может приконнектиться к бэку. Почему такое может происходить и как это исправить? Я пробовал по-разному менять пути, но максимум чего добился - ошибка с 500 изменилась на 404.

Comment: А может, не надо наглеть и ежедневно поднимать сообщение перестановкой одной точки?